# Standard Question object not accessible

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, standard-objects

I am system admin, 
Setup -> Quick Search -> Question is not visible in my setup.

Actually their was a trigger written on it before an year. 
Now while compiling my test cases I am not able to deploy the change set as it is running into compilation error.

How come I am not able to access standard Question object. Are we missing something?

Comment: Have you tried going to Setup -> Quick Search -> FeedItem Triggers? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AygfIAC

Comment: there is a similar thread here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/126669/2602